# Java pass a list type to a generic method?

Tags: java, list, generics

I have written the following method that takes a generic type. How do i pass a list of type Order as the response type?

```
public <T> ServiceResponse<T> fetchGet(String url, Class<T> responseType, boolean authRequired);

// This works just fine
fetchGet("MY_URL", Order.class, true);

// How do i pass a list?
fetchGet("MY_URL", List<Order>.class, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to use `List.class` and do an explicit cast afterwards.  Or you could do the alternate hack of calling `fetchGet("MY_URL", (Class<List<Order>>) (Class) List.class, true);`.

Comment: I'm wondering if jackson framework would know what generic type it should convert my data to. Will give it a try

Comment: Cannot cast Class<List> to Class<List<Order>>>

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using an array instead of a list. I had to pass this to RestTemplate exchange method, and passing an array instead of List worked.

```
fetchGet("MY_URL", Order[].class, true);
```